# How to get around this error when unTarring an archive “tar: Cannot change ownership to uid 1000, gid 1000: Operation not permitted”

Tags: linux, docker, tar, root, ownership

When attempting to untar a file in a docker container with:

```
tar -zvxf training.tar.gz -C data/multi30k
```

I received the following error (`train.de` is a file within the .tar file):

```
tar: train.de Cannot change ownership to uid 1000, gid 1000: Operation not permitted
```

But the file untar's just fine locally. What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 33):

The problem is described [here](https://github.com/habitat-sh/builder/issues/365#issuecomment-382862233). This problem arises when trying to untar in a context where tar thinks it is root (e.g. a Docker container). The solution is to add the flag `--no-same-owner`:

```
tar -zvxf training.tar.gz -C data/multi30k --no-same-owner
```